# Can wildcard character (*) be used in the fine-grained access policy for dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have a Amazon dynamodb table with partition key composed of the user's id (from facebook or google) and other characters. I know wildcard can be used to specify the properties of a fine-grained access policy, but I couldn't get the wildcard in the `dynamodb:LeadingKeys` working.

Here is the working policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
              "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
              "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
              "dynamodb:GetItem",
              "dynamodb:PutItem",
              "dynamodb:Query",
              "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<...>:table/<table-name>"
          ],
          "Condition": {
              "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                  "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                      "g_${accounts.google.com:sub}"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
              "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
              "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
              "dynamodb:GetItem",
              "dynamodb:PutItem",
              "dynamodb:Query",
              "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<...>:table/<table-name>"
          ],
          "Condition": {
              "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                  "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                      "*_${accounts.google.com:sub}"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the solution to this. So instead of using `ForAllValues:StringEquals`, use `ForAllValues:StringLike`.

The working policy is such:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
              "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
              "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
              "dynamodb:GetItem",
              "dynamodb:PutItem",
              "dynamodb:Query",
              "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<...>:table/<table-name>"
          ],
          "Condition": {
              "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                  "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                      "*_${accounts.google.com:sub}"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Took me a while to find this reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_ConditionType

Comment: I'm surprised I've found so few references to this. From the documentation it makes it seem like you can only have row-level access control based on an ENTIRE partition key, which in many circumstances could force course partition keys if you also wanted access control. This offers much more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, the docs aren't very clear on this (as usual with AWS).

Comment: could this theoretically work then for a hash key that was "{cognito_identity_id}:{another_identity_id}". I'm guessing you cant use multiple wild card matching, but maybe two conditions and switch ForAll -> ForAny?