# DynamoDB and GSIs when using access control with IAM policies

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

As a lockdown project I'm introducing myself to the concept of multi-tenancy applications. My simple application has a tenant who has a an online shop front. The shop has product categories each containing many products. My initial thought on database schema is as follows:

```
+====================================================================================+
| Primary Key | Sort Key (GSI PK) | Attribute 1 (GSI SK) | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3 |
|-------------|-------------------|----------------------|-------------|-------------|
| TENANT-uuid | CATEGORY-uuid     | categoryName         | ...         | ...         |
| TENANT-uuid | PRODUCT-uuid      | productName          | ...         | ...         |
| TENANT-uuid | PRODUCT-uuid      | productName          | ...         | ...         |
+====================================================================================+
```

So our GSI looks like so:

```
+=======================================================================================+
| Primary Key   | Sort Key          | Attribute 1 (PK) | Attribute 2 (SK) | Attribute 3 |
|---------------|-------------------|------------------|------------------|-------------|
| CATEGORY-uuid | categoryName      | TENANT-uuid      | CATEGORY-uuid    | ...         |
| PRODUCT-uuid  | productName       | TENANT-uuid      | PRODUCT-uuid     | ...         |
| PRODUCT-uuid  | productName       | TENANT-uuid      | PRODUCT-uuid     | ...         |
+=======================================================================================+
```

If I were to implement the following role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:XXX:XXX:table/XXX"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "TENANT-uuid"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How does the `LeadingKeys` condition work if we're running a query on an index?

---

## Update 1

So upon further inspection it seems one way to do this (for this situation) is to have a GSI with the partition key as the `TENANT-uuid` and the sort key as the item's parent. I've realised I should probably add slightly more information as follows.

Our desired outcomes are:

1. Get list of tenant's categories -> Query with `PK = TENANT-uuid` and `SK BeginsWith "CATEGORY"`
2. Get list of tenant's products -> Query with `PK = TENANT-uuid` and `SK BegingsWith "PRODUCT"`
3. Get list of products in a specific tenant's category -> ???
4. Get single tenant's category -> Query with `PK = TENANT-uuid` and `SK = CATEGORY-uuid`
5. Get single tenant's product -> Query with `PK = TENANT-uuid` and `SK = PRODUCT-uuid`

As it stands the only one that was an issue was number 3. A little reorganisation of the schema as follows seems to work. However it does limit our ability to sort our data slightly.

**Table**

```
+----------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| TenantID (PK/GSI PK) | ItemType (SK) | Data - (GSI SK) | Attribute 2 |
+----------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| TENANT-uuid          | CATEGORY-1    | Category Name   | ...         |
+----------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| TENANT-uuid          | PRODUCT-1     | CATEGORY-1      | ...         |
+----------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| TENANT-uuid          | PRODUCT-2     | CATEGORY-1      | ...         |
+----------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Index**

```
+---------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| TenantID (PK) | Data (SK)     | ItemType   | Attribute 2 |
+---------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| TENANT-uuid   | Category Name | CATEGORY-1 | ...         |
+---------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| TENANT-uuid   | CATEGORY-1    | PRODUCT-1  | ...         |
+---------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| TENANT-uuid   | CATEGORY-1    | PRODUCT-2  | ...         |
+---------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

So now, for number 3, to get a list of products in a specific tenant's category we query the index with `PK = TENANT-uuid` and `SK=CATEGORY-uuid`

This allows us to meet the leadingKeys condition.

However, I'm not sure if this it the best solution. For the time being, in my little project, it works.

Comment: Same question here. My intuitive thought would be that for GSI's, dynamo would scan through all tenants data as usual, but then before returning the result it would filter out any items that violate the IAM policy. But I can't find any documentation to support that theory.

Comment: Have you thought about testing it yourself or posting in the AWS forums? I plan to experiment with this, but it might take me a week or two to get around to.

Comment: Just tested it and it doesn't work. Sort of expected, as it is looking for the tenant information in the primary key, which for the GSI isn't the same as the base table.

Comment: Seriously? What do you mean by it doesn't work? I.e. you can access resources other than those allowed by the policy? That doesn't seem right

Comment: AccessDenied presumably because the primary key on the GSI isn't the TENANT-uuid anymore.

Comment: @ATyshka I've done a little update. Seems there is a workaround by always keeping the `leadingKey` condition as a primary key.

Comment: Yeah I see. The behavior you found does make sense, but it's still rather unfortunate. Having to always use the tenant id as the primary key really limits your flexibility in terms of design patterns and query-ability.

Comment: Just double-checking; Can the IAM policy filter out items that don't comply ? Or will it simply throw a `AccessDenied` error if any of the returned items fails the policy ? Filtering out probably seems far-fetched, as it would open a whole new can of worms wrg to scanned count, consumed capacity etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After almost giving up, I have found a solution. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605010/can-wildcard-character-be-used-in-the-fine-grained-access-policy-for-dynamod) describing how you can use wildcards in the IAM policy. Then in your GSI's, you could prefix each of your Id's with a tenant ID. Using your second table as an example, replace `CATEGORY-uuid` with `TENANT-uuid-CATEGORY-uuid`

And then your policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:XXX:XXX:table/XXX"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "TENANT-uuid*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tested this quick, it works just fine, and this is the approach I plan to use in my multi-tenant app.

Comment: Just tested and it does seem to work. Seems to end up getting quite messy, but I'm sure I can work that out!

Comment: Yes it does make things slightly more visually cluttered, but in my opinion it's worth the extra flexibility